# Turbulence in blood

Tags: cardiology, hematology, blood-circulation

Turbulence in blood flow is known to indicate diseased or obstructed arteries. Techniques to measure turbulence in blood flow are mostly based on turbulence kinetic energy measurments using MRI [e.g., Ha H *et al*., PLOS ONE 11(3), (2016) (1)].

Are there any other well known techniques to measure turbulent blood flow, besides those based on MRI?

(1) https://doi.org/10.1371/journal.pone.0151540

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Whatever constricts an orifice, whatever dilates a cavity, whatever establishes an orifice or cavity where none shall be, will disturb the even flow of blood and produce vibrations and a murmur.
>
> —Samuel Jones Gee (1839–1911)

Turbulent blood flow is classically detected by auscultation (listening). Turbulent flow across the valves of the heart causes murmurs. A certain amount of external pressure applied to a brachial artery allows turbulent flow, which you can hear, which is how you measure blood pressure. Carotid bruit's are a sound produced by turbulence in the carotid artery.  You can reference any physical examination textbook, e.g., Bate's for information on this method of detecting turbulent flow. There's an NCBI books [Clinical Methods](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/books/NBK201/?term=turbulence) textbook that you can search for turbulence.

Turbulence can also be detected by one of a variety of ultrasound methods. The specific measurements taken using these methods are typically anatomic measurements (e.g., thickness of a tissue, distance across a valve), peak flow, overall direction of flow, and gradient measurements, since those are the markers that have been used to characterize disease and/or outcomes. However [they *can* detect turbulence](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/?term=6844621). Quantitative measurements of turbulence just aren't used experimentally.